# Can I whitelist IPs to work on my Git repo?

Tags: git, github, ip

I want my Git repos to be setup only on particular desktops/laptops. Any good way to pursue that?

Comment: Upvoting, because of unconstructive downvote

Answer (score 2):

git does neither know something about authorization nor about authentication.

What you are trying is not possible with git.

BUT you can use some tools like [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/index.html) to set up something similar based on ssh-keys. If your really want to restrict access also by IP you need something like a firewall on a server where the repo was intialy created.

Answer (score 2):

Github's business model is that you can have public repos for free, but you need to have a payed subscription to have private repos.

Whitelisting IPs is not a good idea. The IP address of a typical home internet connection may change anytime the ISP wants it to change and enterprises will have many hundred or thousand users behind a single public IP. Both ways you will have problems allowing the proper user to a specific repo.

You might have a look at Git hosting services that offer private repos with authentication (free).

Answer (score 1):

- This is not possible in 'git', since git is not responsible for hosting your repositories.
- whitelisting the IP will not restrict the repository access to individual computers, just the external IP they connect from (which sometimes changes for residential internet subscribers).

The repository hosting is done via a software like Github, Gitlab, Bitbucket, etc.

*Self Hosted Solution*

If you are managing the server yourself (Like in the case of Bitbucket Server, Gitlab EE, Github Business) this can be done by [whitelisting IP addresses using iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/30026/whitelist-allowed-ips-in-out-using-iptables), or by using [afw](https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.9/admin/guides/installation/configuring-built-in-firewall-rules/).

Note that this will restrict access to the entire server, not just the repository.

*Cloud Solutions*

Assuming you are not using enterprise cloud solutions, I suggest restricting access to the repository by making the repository private.

Gitlab, and Bitbucket will allow you to create private repositories for free.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub Enterprise - $21 USD/month - (and GitHub One) support IP allow lists:

https://github.com/pricing -> Security & Compliance -> IP allow list

Note that you can't just sign-up / pay for this plan by yourself, you would need to contact a sales team to get started and there would likely be a minimum of seats requirement.

Otherwise, GitHub doesn't currently support this for their other plans.

Comment: And you can now (Aug. 2022) [check whether a particular IP address would be allowed by any of the enabled entries in your IP allow list, even if the list is not currently enabled.](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-08-24-check-whether-an-ip-is-permitted-within-ip-allow-list/).